# Java Chatting program cannot see any messages on JtextArea(Netbeans!!)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Before the main quest, I wanna say excouse me for my poor english (I'm not native english speaker)

I have a big school project, and for the project, I decided to create a simple java chatting program.
My teacher said it's ok to use open source code if I write down from where I took that code.

I took the code from here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqBmsLvWU14&t=411s

Video creates program in JFrame form and it works for me if I do exactly like the video. But, if I just extend JFrame without creating a file in JFrame form, the code does not work. I think you will see what do I mean if you watch the video and my codes.

```
package Chat;
//Server 

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Chat_Server extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton jb1 = new JButton("Invite");
JButton Name = new JButton("Name");
JButton Enter = new JButton("Enter");
JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();
static JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(500,500);
JTextField textfield = new JTextField(35);
static ServerSocket SS;
static Socket S;
static DataInputStream DIS;
static DataOutputStream DOS; 

public Chat_Server(){
    jp1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jp1.add(jb1); jp1.add(Name);
    jb1.addActionListener(this);
    Name.addActionListener(this);
    jp2.add(textarea);
    jp3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jp3.add(textfield); jp3.add(Enter);
    add(jp1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(jp2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jp3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String name;
    if(e.getSource()==jb1)
       Call();
    if(e.getSource()==Name){
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type your name");
        String Servername = name;
    }
    if(e.getSource()==Enter){
         try{
    String MessageOut= "";
    MessageOut = textfield.getText();
    DOS.writeUTF(MessageOut);
    }catch( Exception ex){

    }
    }
}
public void Call(){
    Chat_Client CC = new Chat_Client();
}
public static void main (String[] args){
    Chat_Server cs = new Chat_Server();
     String MessageIn = "";
    try{
     SS = new ServerSocket(1000);
     Socket S = SS.accept();
     DIS = new DataInputStream(S.getInputStream());
     DOS = new DataOutputStream(S.getOutputStream());



     while (!MessageIn.equals("Stop the chat")){
         MessageIn = DIS.readUTF();
         textarea.setText(textarea.getText()+"\n"+MessageIn);
     }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

  }
   }
```

---------------------------------End next code----------------------------------

```
package Chat;

import static Chat.Chat_Server.SS;

 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.DataInputStream;
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;

public class Chat_Client extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton Name = new JButton("Namn");
JButton Enter = new JButton("Enter");
JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
JPanel jp3 = new JPanel();
static JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(500,500);
JTextField textfield = new JTextField(35);
static ServerSocket SS;
static Socket S;
static DataInputStream DIS;
static DataOutputStream DOS; 

public Chat_Client(){
   jp1.add(Name);

    Name.addActionListener(this);
    jp2.add(textarea);
    jp3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    jp3.add(textfield); jp3.add(Enter);
    add(jp1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(jp2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jp3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String name;

    if(e.getSource()==Name){
        name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ange ditt namn");
        String Kundname = name;
    }
    if(e.getSource()==Enter){
         try{
    String MessageOut= "";
    MessageOut = textfield.getText();
    DOS.writeUTF(MessageOut);
    }catch( Exception ex){

    }
    }
}
        public static void main (String[] args){
    Chat_Client cc = new Chat_Client();
    String MessageIn = ""; 
    try{
     S = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1000);
     DIS = new DataInputStream(S.getInputStream());
     DOS = new DataOutputStream(S.getOutputStream());

     while (!MessageIn.equals("Stop the chat")){
         MessageIn = DIS.readUTF();
         textarea.setText(textarea.getText()+"\n"+MessageIn);
     }
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }

   }
   }
```

If I click on the JButton with name Enter, the text must be visible on the other screen's JTextArea, like at the video but in my case, Java does not send anything and I don't get why is that so :(

Comment: Don't copy code. Learn ideas, and copy them, but write all your own code and you will understand it and avoid problems like this one.

Comment: Also, if that tutorial is telling you to use a bunch of static fields and empty catch blocks as you're doing, then it's not worth watching or learning from.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Yep, that code is pretty much horrible. For example it is **absolutely horrible** that all those *catch* blocks are **empty**. That means that any error message is just thrown away.

Comment: Really, your "example" code is horrible. I agree with DontKnowGuy ... you really much better turn here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ ... and start working through those tutorials. You see, starting with a project that requires A) UI components B) socket communication ... as your first "java thing" ... that is totally overburdening you.

Comment: But please I need help why my thing is not working it's my school project and I have only one week left

Comment: I have to agree with the others. You're trying to combine 2 complex Java fields and don't appear to understand something as basic as exception handling is a recipe for disaster. Either resign yourself to 2 weeks of intense study or choose something easier to do.

Comment: @GhostCat but please It would be very very very very thankful if you could give me just a little hint why my code does not work.. I did almost the same like the code (Difference is just he creates program in JFrame form but I create in java class and create all listeners, constructor myself)

Comment: Sorry pal, for me weekend starts in 15 minutes.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels   but in the video, program worked perfectly (I did it for a test, it worked perfectly for me also ) with empty exceptions..  But my code, which I have just edited some ActionListeners and created aconstructor, does not work I have no idea why ... can you give me just a little little hint why my program does not work??

Comment: @javaprogrammer Please first change your catch blocks at least to print stack trace. Do e.printStackTrace(); in each of your catch blocks. Then, run the program and let us know if you get any errors. Otherwise, just start fresh as others have suggested. The code is really of very low standard. Better try the standard Java tutorial instead.

Comment: This is not to make it work. It is just to try and see where your code may be failing.

Comment: *"..it's my school project and I have only one week left"* We are not in control of your time management. You are. From what has happened so far, it seems this project will be late. In future, best not to mention your time constraints. People who offer help for free, typically want to help people who have the time to follow our suggestions (read: people with better time-management skills). As for me, I'm going to do that now. Good luck with it.

Comment: You have to learn a lot and I think you could finish this app in one week, but only if you had former experience with OOP and programming in general - I guess you don't have much, if any. If you want to build a car, you need to know a lot about mechanics. If you want to build an ship, you need to know a lot too. If you want to build amphibious vehicle, you need to know even more. At this stage, you're trying to weld together a car with a boat. If you want to complete any project, write something simpler. If you want to learn how to write such an app, learn about Swing/JavaFX, plus networking.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have not registered your 'Enter' button with any ActionListener. Add below line. (you have it neither in server nor in client - add in both files in the constructors as you did for other controls)

```
Enter.addActionListener(this);
```

Also, your textarea doesn't seem to be properly visible in your window. Change your textarea size to as small as (20,20) instead of (500,500) which seem to be going out of your panel and not fully visible. After making these changes, it should work. Change the size later to whichever size that fits and suits your panel. I suggest learn layouts to better manage your controls positions.

Please refer a standard tutorial for learning, instead of going for such unclear and not so standard tutorials.